# can't run docker in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, docker-daemon

I had tried to install docker like I read in lots of site with the same steps, but it didn't work and always send me that error massage:`docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.` and I didn't could find solution that work.

After that I tried to test a bit the `sudo snap`, and I was surprised to discover that I can install docker using `sudo snap install docker` and its look like it worked, but when I run the `sudo docker run -dt centos bash`, I had got the same error.
It's not only a issue with CentOS, I had tried this with kali, mint, ubuntu, and fedora, no one of them worked, and the error is always the same/

thanks for help.

Comment: Did you checked the status with:  `sudo systemctl status docker `

If it is not running then:  `sudo systemctl start docker `

Comment: I tried this, with a fault.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount /var/run/docker.sock

```
sudo docker run -dt -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock centos bash
```